# SSH SCP files from a list

Tags: ssh, scp

I have a specific list of files that I need to copy from a remote server. Is this possible with SCP?

I know I can copy individual files using `scp {user_name}@{host}:{filepath} .` , but is there any way to take a `.csv` or `.txt` and run a foreach loop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
while read file; do scp "user@host:$file" .; done <  files
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense. Follow up question: I am prompted for my password each iteration of the loop; is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure user:password@host:$file will work. Anyway, there is a thread about it stackoverflow.com/questions/20430119/send-password-when-using-scp-to-copy-files-from-one-server-to-another

Answer (score 2):

I found that it was easier to use tar with a list then send the files individually via scp:

`tar -czvf archive.tar.gz -T file-list.txt && scp archive.tar.gz user@host:/path/`

I use this on systems that don't have rsync available, this way you also avoid iterating password prompts or TCP/SSH connection limits.

Answer (score 0):

```
scp `cat /path/to/file` login@remote_host
```